# Cancel rewrite and redirect removing last directory with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a page with this settings:

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)show(/|.*)$
RewriteRule . /demo/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

For example, when you request the page http://example.com/demo/any_folder/ it loads http://example.com/demo/index.php without changing the URL, to retrieve data from a database for example. Well, this works.
But I want to add and exception.
I need a condition that if you visit http://example.com/demo/any_folder/show it loads the same URL removing the word "show" but avoiding the redirect that is actually defined. So, it will load http://example.com/demo/any_folder/ and not http://example.com/demo/index.php. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you want `http://example.com/demo/any_folder/show` to redirect to `http://example.com/demo/any_folder/`, how is it going to be any difference from a any other request for `http://example.com/demo/any_folder/`?

Comment: I don't know :( I think there's no way to do this, but I've made this in another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be something different about the URL to not be redirected to `index.php`. The following `.htaccess` code adds a query parameter `?show` to tell the two URLs apart.

Since, the redirection is internal; the user never gets to see the parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /demo/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/show/?$ $1?show [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^show [NC]
RewriteRule . /demo/index.php [L]
```

Comment: @Egatuts Muy bien. Estoy feliz para usted. Excuse me if this isn't correct. :)